# Calling a list of posts based on category

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im trying to call a list os posts based on a category, but it isnt working, is giving me the error:`Non-static method App\Category::posts() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`.
I already tried calling from both sides, going threw the post model methdos or categories, but same error message. Can figure out what im doing wrong.

Database:

```
Posts:
-id;
-title;
-text;

Categories:
-id;
-name;
-internal_name;

category_post:
-id;
-post_id;
-category_id
```

Controller:

```
public function categoryPostList($category)
{
     $category = Category::posts()->where('internal_name',$category)->first(); 
     $posts = Post::categories()->where('category_id',$category->id)->get(); 
     dd($posts)
}
```

Model Post:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
    }       
}
```

Model Category:

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Comment: The relation should be `belongsToMany` not `belongsTo`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all if relationship is many to many (you're using pivot table) your relation should be `belongsToMany()`, but not `belongsTo()`.

To load relation You should use `with()` method. For example, if you want to load one category with all it's posts:

```
Post::where('category_id', $category->id)->with('categories')->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) as:

```
$category = Category::where('internal_name',$category)->first();

$posts = Post::whereHas('categories', function($q) use($category) {
    $q->where('category_id',$category->id);
})->get();
```

Or

```
$category = Category::where('internal_name',$category)->first();
$posts = $category->posts;
```

> The `whereHas` method is used to put "where" conditions on your has
>   queries.